# Movement time of object with constant jerk, limited acceleration and velocity

Tags: limits, physics, kinematics

A product is initially at rest on a conveyor belt:

[image: Product on Conveyor]

The initial conditions of the product can be described as follows:$$x_i=0$$ $$v_i=0$$ $$a_i=0$$$$j_i = j⋆ $$.

The product will be moved forward distance of exactly `Δx` (known) to position it under the conveyor belt:

[image: Product on Conveyor Moved]

When the movement is complete, the product will be sprayed for a few moments, so it must come to a complete rest at this point:

[image: Product on Conveyor Sprayed]

The conveyor, which must move the product into position, will complete the movement in the minimum time possible.

The conveyor's control system will apply a constant jerk of `j⋆` (known), `-j⋆` (known) or zero.

However, the conveyor must obey these limits:

- It has a max velocity of `v⋆` (known),
- a max acceleration of `a⋆` (known),
- a max deceleration of `d⋆` (known).

Assume the product does not slide or slip on the conveyor.

**How long will it take the product to complete the movement of `Δx`?**

*Side Note:*

At first glance, it seems as though the problem can be solved by a simple application of the kinematic equation for one-dimensional motion with constant jerk (and its derivatives):
$$x = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a_0 t^2 + \frac{1}{6}jt^3$$
However, the limits `v⋆`, `a⋆` and `d⋆` pose a major problem. For some values of `Δx`, the conveyor may not even reach max velocity, max acceleration, or max deceleration.  Therefore, there will be 8 possible scenarios in which different combinations of these limits are reached.  To assist with this part of the problem, I have created a decision chart that illustrates the different possible scenarios:

[Conveyor Limit Decision Chart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzaOAMbMT9r6d3BPb2VoRG9kMjA/view?usp=sharing)

As `Δx` gets smaller and smaller, the possibilities range from all three limits reached...

[image: All limits reached]

... to no limits reached...

[image: No limits reached]

... making it hard to describe the time passed during the movement with a single function.  I am stumped at this point- how do I predict which limits will be met and which will not?

Comment: What do you mean by "acceleration" and "deceleration"? Assuming this problem is in more than 1 dimension, acceleration is typically defined as a vector quantity, and deceleration becomes difficult to define such that it is distinct from acceleration.

Comment: @Kajelad Yes defining acceleration differently than deceleration in multiple dimensions would be tricky.  This problem is just in 1 dimension.  To keep things simple, acceleration is defined as the increase in magnitude of velocity over time, and deceleration is defined as the decrease in the magnitude of velocity over time.

Comment: Shall the object also be finally still, i.e. still at its destination?

Comment: Do you have more information about the magnitude of your *known* parameters? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: As I understand the question, we want to find a twice-differentiable function $x:[0,T]\to\mathbb R$ satisfying the conditions
$$\begin{gather}
x(0)=x'(0)=x''(0)=0, \\
x(T)=X,\\
x'\le v,\\
d\le x''\operatorname{sgn}(x')\le a, \\
x'''\in\{-j,0,j\} \text{ wherever $x'''$ is defined,}
\end{gather}$$
and such that $T$ is as small as possible. (I've renamed $x^*$ to $x$ and $x$ to $X$.) Is this interpretation correct, @Luminaire?

Comment: @Rahul I think you also have $x'(T)=x''(T)=0$. In addition, $d<0$, and I can think you can safely assume that $x'\ge 0$ if $X>0$

Comment: @Andrei: You're right, I missed that part of the question (and I should have written $-d$ for the lower bound). I agree that $x'\ge0$ should be true in the optimal solution, but I don't think we should assume it as part of the question.

Comment: @md2perpe- yes, it must be finally still.  I updated the question to explain why!  @Andrei- I have tried applying the kinematic equation for one-dimensional motion with constant jerk.  I am able to solve the problem by making certain assumptions- I.e. the conveyor is able to meet max velocity, max acceleration and max deceleration.  However, determining which assumptions are safe to make has stumped me. @Rahul yes that's exactly right- and what has stumped me.  We must determine what `x'''` will look like in order for the movement to take the minimum amount of time.

Comment: Nice edit! I hope the question will get enough reopen votes now.

Comment: Hypothesis: The jerk as a function of time takes the values $j^*,0,-j^*,0,-j^*,0,j^*$, in that order, for consecutive time intervals between times $0\le t_1\le t_2\le\dots\le t_7$. That is, the jerk is $j^*$ between time $0$ and $t_1$, $0$ between $t_1$ and $t_2$, and so on. Some of those intervals may be degenerate (for example, you could have $t_1=t_2$). I believe the ending conditions and the kinematic constraints can be expressed as linear equations and inequalities on the variables $t_1,\dots,t_7$, after which minimizing $t_7$ becomes a linear programming problem.

Comment: @Rahul I went and looked up "linear programming problem," and it sounds exactly like what I am facing!  I am *very* interested in learning how to solve this as a linear programming problem.  I tried expressing the kinematic constraints as linear inequalities, but I ran into a problem- the velocity constraint is not linear! $$\\v_{\star}> \frac{1}{2}j(t_1-t_0)^2 + a_\star(t_2-t_1)+ a_\star(t_3-t_2) + \frac{1}{2}j(t_3-t_2)^2$$.  Did I express the kinematic constraint wrong, or is there a way to make this expression linear?

Comment: No, you're right, the velocity constraint isn't linear. My bad...